# map key value pair with entity properties in entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ef-database-first

Below is my code for entity and a function where I need to map entity **TblEmployee** from a key value pair.

In foreach loop I am getting values based on keys, what should be the best approach to do it?

```
  public class TblEmployee
            {       
                public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }      
            }
 public int Create()      
        {
          tblEmployee employee = new tblEmployee();
                    using (var ctx = new theparkeee_testEntities())
                    {
                        foreach (string key in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys)
                        {
                            string value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[key];
                            //how to map value from key value pair to entity employee.
                        }
                    }
         }
```

Comment: I would suggest that using a set based approach would be far better than calling a stored procedure for every row. Table valued parameters can do this kind of thing a lot more efficiently.

Comment: m not using stored procedure here, just finding any option. I m not aware of set based approach, let me surf more abt this..

Comment: set based approach is something different i think. Here i am getting values from From based on key value pair and just want to map existing entity..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Reflection` to get the Properties of an object by their name with `Type.GetProperty(string name)`. After you got the `PropertyInfo`, you can use `SetValue` to assign a value to it.

```
foreach (string key in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys) {

     // note that "value" is a reserved word, do not use it as variable name
    string val = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[key];

    var propertyInfo = typeof(TblEmployee).GetProperty(key); // can maybe be moved outside of the loop
    if (propertyInfo != null) {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(employee, val); 
    }
}
```

This will work for string properties. If the property is of another type, you have to find the correct type (again, using reflection) and cast the string value before assigning it.

Note that this is **not the correct approach** to store data in MVC. You should not work with the `Request.Form` directly, instead your POST action should accept a ViewModel that can be mapped (e.g. using [Automapper](https://automapper.org/)) to the DB entity. I.e. let the ASP [ModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) do its work, instead of reinventing the wheel!

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(MyViewModel postData) {
    var employee = Mapper.Map<TblEmployee>(postData);
    _ctx.Employees.Add(employee);
    _ctx.SaveChanges();
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: actually m working on angular where i need to post data(including file) on web api so this is the approach i used to send all data in form, i know in mvc we are using model as parameter. I also tried it from last 4-5 days but i didn't get the file on api post. Will let u know if it works. Thanks for the answer..